# Swift/xcode/iOS: Using Firebase to retrieve data already collected and displaying it in a separate view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm working on an app that allows you to write and see posts, kind of like Twitter would allow. The database I'm using is Firebase and I have it receiving information when a command is completed. Every time I intend to receive information, I do and I can view all of it within Firebase. However, I would like to then display the information from my database in a ***SEPARATE*** view controller (using Table View cells, each post in a different cell). I have found tutorials that would allow the info received in the database to be seen within that view controller, however I cannot find a way to do so within a different view controller. To simplify the question, I want to take the data I already have and display it in a different view controller than the one where the info was received.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to gather an array of post objects within that view controller, you could use local notifications to pass the array to the separate view controller.

From where you got the data:

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
//Name of notification is "postsRetrieved"
nc.postNotificationName("postsRetrieved", object:nil,userInfo:["posts":postsArray])
```

Now, add a listener to the separate view controller

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.addObserver(self, selector: "postsFunction:", name: "postsRetrieved", object: nil)
```

Lastly, implement the selector from your listener ("postsFunction")

```
func postsFunction(notification:NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:Dictionary<Array,Array!> = notification.userInfo as Dictionary<Array,Array!>
    let postsArray = userInfo["postsArray"]

    //Now, use this array as your table data source
}
```